# Livewire (Laravel) Get validation error inside controller not the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want the errors show of the controller not the View

```
    public $name;
    public $email;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];


    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate();

        Contact::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ]);
    }
```

**In Laravel, i can bring the errors array in this way, but how can I bring them back from Livewire?**

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return dd($validator->messages());    
}
```

Comment: The `validate()` method throws an exception, which Laravel catches. You can check the `$errors` variable in blade, or check via the `@error` directive

Comment: Like I said, it's just an exception. You can catch it yourself,  `try { $this->validate(); } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) { $e->errors(); }`

Comment: And to add to that, you should probably re-throw the exception at the end of your `catch` block, you can do that by adding `throw $e;` before the `}` that closes the catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$this->validate()` will throw an exception when there are validation-errors. This exception can be caught in a `try`/`catch`, and if its not caught, Laravel will catch it with its global exception-handler (which will enable the `@error` directive in blade, or the `$errors` variable in your view.

You can intercept this by catching it yourself and handling the logic you want to apply. Its also recommended that you re-throw the exception after that, so that execution of the method stops, and that you get the default Laravel behavior in your view.

```php
public function submit()
{
    try {
        $this->validate(); 
    } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) { 
        // Use $e->errors() to find the validationerrors
        // Add your custom logic here. 

        // Re-throw the exception once done
        throw $e;
    }

    Contact::create([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

same like Laravel does it you can achieve it using the Validator::make

```
$validation = Validator::make($data,$rules);

if($validation->fails()) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Where says that this approach depend of the rules quantity or data?